# Highcharts change crosshairs color by number of visible series

Tags: colors, highcharts, tooltip, visible

What we are trying to do is to:

- display crosshairs only if number of visible series > 1 (color: black)
- otherwise disable crosshairs or alternatively set color transparent

Here are our problems:

- independent of the number of visible series the crosshairs is not shown for the first hover (but for all subsequent hovers)
- our main problem is that the color is not changing although the console.log displays that the color is correctly set due to the number of visible series

Please see the fiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/D5DME/)

Thanks for your suggestions!

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'area',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic and Estimated Worldwide Population Growth by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        title: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Billions'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value / 1000;
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {

            // show crosshairs only if visible series >1, else transparent
            var nVisible = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
                if (chart.series[i].visible) {
                    nVisible++;
                };
                if (nVisible > 1) {
                    break;
                };
            };

            if (nVisible > 1) {
                chart.options.tooltip.crosshairs = {
                    width: 1.5,
                    dashStyle: 'solid',
                    color: 'black'
                };
            } else {
                chart.options.tooltip.crosshairs = {
                    color: 'transparent'
                };

            };
            console.log(chart.options.tooltip.crosshairs.color);
            return this.y + ' Billions';
        },
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.95)'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            lineColor: '#666666',
            lineWidth: 1,
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#666666'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Asia',
        data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
    }, {
        name: 'Africa',
        data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
    }, {
        name: 'Europe',
        data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
    }, {
        name: 'America',
        data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
    }, {
        name: 'Oceania',
        data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
    }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add crosshair in real time, instead when chart is initialized, enable crosshair and then manage color by `attr()` updating. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/D5DME/3/

Code:

```
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: [{
            width: 1.5,
            dashStyle: 'solid',
            color: 'black'
        }, false],
        formatter: function () {

            // show crosshairs only if visible series >1, else transparent
            var nVisible = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.series.chart.series.length; i++) {
                if (this.series.chart.series[i].visible) {
                    nVisible++;
                };
            };

            if(this.series.chart.tooltip.crosshairs[0]) {
                if (nVisible > 1) {
                    this.series.chart.tooltip.crosshairs[0].attr({
                        stroke: 'black'
                    });
                } else {
                    this.series.chart.tooltip.crosshairs[0].attr({
                        stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                    });
                }
            }
            return this.y + ' Billions';
        },
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.95)'
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is your fiddle working? I can't see any crosshairs although you enabled it in your code. Would be great if you can help me again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the tooltip code is the wrong place to be trying this. I would use the series hide and show event handlers to detect how many series were showing (a simple counter which increments in show and decrements in hide would work).

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.events.hide

You could try the chart setting options depending on the count.

However, I'm not sure that simply settting chart.options.tootlip. will work dynamically the way you want.